# How to access external mysql database with aws lambda in python (without vpc) through vpn and using ssl

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda

I want to connect to an external mysql database from aws lambda in python (through vpn and with using ssl).

It does work via shell
`mysql --host=xxx.yyy.de --user=xxx -p --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-ca=/Users/.../ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/Users/.../client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/Users/.../client-key.pem`

And it does work locally with aws SAM Client

```
import mysql.connector
import boto3

dynamotable_name = "testTable03"

def connect_db():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="xxx.yyy.de",
        user="xxx",
        password="zzz",
        database="database",
        ssl_ca="ca-cert.pem",
        ssl_cert="client-cert.pem",
        ssl_key="client-key.pem"
    )
    cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    cur.execute("select * from measure order by measure_id desc limit 10;")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    return result


def fill_dynamodb(data):
    for x in data:
        measure_id = x[0]
        sensor_id = x[1]
        sensor_value = x[2]
        location_id = x[3]
        datetime = x[4]

        # put items into an existing DynamoDB table
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
        table = dynamodb.Table(dynamotable_name)
        table.put_item(
            Item={
                'measure_id': str(measure_id),
                'sensor_id': sensor_id,
                'sensor_value': sensor_value,
                'location_id': location_id,
                'datetime': str(datetime)
            }
        )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    fill_dynamodb(connect_db())
```

I always got this error :

{"errorMessage": "2003: can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.yyy.de:3306' (110 Connection timed out)", "errorType": "InterfaceError",

Is it the internet access? or has it something todo with vpn?

Answer (score 0):

I created a VPC with public and private Subnets and a NAT Gateway, so I could give my Lambda function a static Elastic IP address, which got access to the extern DB.